# odbc do not show utf8 on server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, plesk, php-5.2

i use `odbc in php`. i had problem with `utf8` and solved it with `iconv()` function. but when i upload it on server `utf8` character not show correctly(on local with `easy-php sqlserver-2008 r2` every thing is ok). any idea?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses UCS2 rather than UTF8 to store it's data. If you are passing in UTF8 the data will be garbage in SQL Server.

Comment: i use **iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1256', $temp);** and it works good on local but when i upload on site not working.